# Related products select button missing and Size attribute in related products

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, related-products

On [this page](http://www.futurum.cc/en/shop/shorts-and-tights/bib-shorts-pepijn-i-original-black.html) I have added Related products.

1. where is the select button, to select a product?
2. those shirts are in different sizes. How can I display the `Size`
   attribute here? So users are able to select their size directly?

Answer (score 1):

If related products  type is configurable or have custom option(with required) type then cannot be cart directly.

So you need to customization, and in that case you can use this link [Configurable product on list.phtml page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/configurable-product-on-list-phtml-page)